# "Task function must be specified at Gulp.set" error when running gulp

Tags: gulp

I always have the same error when installing gulp:

```
C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\Sites CT Graphics\colpaertmarc.be>gulp
assert.js:350
throw err;
^
```

> AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
>       at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\Sites CT Graphics\colpaertmarc.be\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
>       at Gulp.task (C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\Sites CT Graphics\colpaertmarc.be\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\Sites CT Graphics\colpaertmarc.be\gulpfile.js:19:6)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)

Comment: You need to show your gulpfile.js for us to help.

Answer (score 4):

This error occurs after you upgrade your gulp version from **3.*** to **4.***. 
If you don't want to downgrade gulp, then you will have to rewrite **gulp tasks** to be valid with **v4** api. Here is example how to rewrite simple gulp task from api notation used in **v3** to notation compatiable with **v4**.

## Gulp v3

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

// Deleting resources task
gulp.task('clearResources', function() {
  console.log('Deleting resources');
});

// Default gulp task
gulp.task('default', ['clearResources'], function() {
  console.log('Running default task');
});
```

## Gulp v4

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

// Delete resources function
function clearResources() {
  console.log('Deleting resources');
};

// Gulp task(s)
exports.clear = clearResources;
exports.default = gulp.series(clearResources);
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be related to the Gulp V4, there's two options:

- Update your code to V4 ([Article related](https://www.liquidlight.co.uk/blog/how-do-i-update-to-gulp-4/) )

OR

- Downgrade gulp version

To downgrade you need to update your `package.json` with

```
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
```

And then remove node_module folder and reinstall npm packages

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Answer (score 2):

**GULP 4**

```
const { series, parallel } = require('gulp');

gulp.task('clear', gulp.series( async function(){
  // your code
}));

gulp.task('build', gulp.series( async function(){
  // Your code
}));

gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch('./javascripts/**/*.js', gulp.series('clear','build'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('clear','build','watch'));
```

When I had upgraded the gulp version from ^3.9.1 to ^4.0.2, It worked. Maybe, this code will help you.